# Ubuntu version description

Tags: 14.04

Does anybody know the command to find out how long the Ubuntu version I am using right now will last? I tried lsb_release -a but that only gave me what version of Ubuntu I have (14.04)

Comment: See also this link, [The Ubuntu lifecycle and release cadence](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are thinking of `ubuntu-support-status`?

My output looks like this

```
Support status summary of 'Enterprise':

You have 1 packages (0.0%) supported until June 2017 (9m)
You have 134 packages (5.3%) supported until May 2017 (3y)
You have 2004 packages (79.7%) supported until May 2019 (5y)
You have 72 packages (2.9%) supported until February 2015 (9m)

You have 10 packages (0.4%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 293 packages (11.7%) that are unsupported

Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2019.

Run with --show-unsupported, --show-supported or --show-all to see more details
```

Comment: My output shows this: Support status summary of 'ubuntu':

You have 9 packages (0.5%) supported until June 2017 (9m)
You have 9 packages (0.5%) supported until February 2015 (9m)
You have 1664 packages (96.1%) supported until May 2019 (5y)

You have 0 packages (0.0%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 50 packages (2.9%) that are unsupported

Run with --show-unsupported, --show-supported or --show-all to see more details

Answer (score 0):

### ubuntu-distro-info

provides information about Ubuntu's distributions

```
$ ubuntu-distro-info -raf -yeol
Ubuntu 4.10 "Warty Warthog" -4563
Ubuntu 5.04 "Hoary Hedgehog" -4379
Ubuntu 5.10 "Breezy Badger" -4215
Ubuntu 6.06 LTS "Dapper Drake" -3392
Ubuntu 6.10 "Edgy Eft" -3837
Ubuntu 7.04 "Feisty Fawn" -3660
Ubuntu 7.10 "Gutsy Gibbon" -3479
Ubuntu 8.04 LTS "Hardy Heron" -2725
Ubuntu 8.10 "Intrepid Ibex" -3102
Ubuntu 9.04 "Jaunty Jackalope" -2926
Ubuntu 9.10 "Karmic Koala" -2738
Ubuntu 10.04 LTS "Lucid Lynx" -1997
Ubuntu 10.10 "Maverick Meerkat" -2391
Ubuntu 11.04 "Natty Narwhal" -2190
Ubuntu 11.10 "Oneiric Ocelot" -1997
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS "Precise Pangolin" -549
Ubuntu 12.10 "Quantal Quetzal" -1625
Ubuntu 13.04 "Raring Ringtail" -1734
Ubuntu 13.10 "Saucy Salamander" -1563
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr" 172
Ubuntu 14.10 "Utopic Unicorn" -1192
Ubuntu 15.04 "Vivid Vervet" -1008
Ubuntu 15.10 "Wily Werewolf" -827
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus" 907
Ubuntu 16.10 "Yakkety Yak" -464
Ubuntu 17.04 "Zesty Zapus" -287
Ubuntu 17.10 "Artful Aardvark" -100
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS "Bionic Beaver" 1642
Ubuntu 18.10 "Cosmic Cuttlefish" 264
```

will give you a list of all versions and  display number of days until specified version reaches the eol.

More info on this [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/distro-info.1.html).